# How do I make Ubuntu ask for a password when logging in?

Tags: login, password

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 and selected the option to automatically log in to my account when the laptop starts.

But now I want to change it so it asks me for my password when it starts. I can't find any option for that.

Answer (score 2):

Open the **System Settings** application, then click on the **User Accounts** icon.  In the top right corner, you will have to *unlock* the setting.  Once unlocked, select the user on the left, and turn **Automatic Login** off.

[image: User Accounts Screenshot]